# Evitar que la app se deje de escuchar android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, audio, mediaplayer

Tengo una app en Android Studio que reproduce un audio en streaming.

Al abrirse la app se empieza a reproducir, cuando le doy "pausa" solamente el volumen baja a 0, osea que todo el tiempo se esta reproduciendo, en ningun momento realmente pauso ni detengo el audio en streaming

Uso Media Player,y funciona bien, pero al bloquear el dispositivo se deja de escuchar a los 15 minutos.

La app se compila bien, se genera bien la app y se instala sin problemas.

En el AndroidManifest le doy solo los permisos de INTERNET y ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

¿Como le hago para que el audio se escuche hasta que se cierre la app y no antes?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private Button play;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false;
    FloatingActionButton splay;
    String stream = "http://IP:PUERTO/;";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        splay = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.playChido);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

        splay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(started){
                    started = false;
                    splay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0f, 0f);

                } else {
                    splay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_stop);
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try{
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(prepared){
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: te genera algún error? muéstranos tu bloque de código en el que llamas a tu media player, es difícil decirte que es, cuando no vemos código

Comment: PD: deberías tomar el [tour] para conocer el sitio, y de paso te llevas una flamante [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) ! :D

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, ya edite la publicación con el codigo :)

Comment: cada vez que comienze una reproduccion, se inicializa el media player:
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); y cada vez que se detenga (release) agregar mediaPlayer = null;